# Sum of column in sqlDataframe without using groupBy or agg functions in scala/spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

For a dataframe given below, i want a new column in dataframe which should have constant value of sum of freq column.

```
+------+----+
|number|freq|
+------+----+
|     8|   1| 
|     6|   2|     
|     2|   4|    
+------+----+
```

The result should look like

```
+------+----+-------+
|number|freq|new_col|
+------+----+-------+
|     8|   1|      7|
|     6|   2|      7|
|     2|   4|      7|
+------+----+-------+
```

and i want this without `groupBy` or `agg`.
I tried :

```
var x = sum(df("freq"))
df.withColumn("new_col",lit(x))
```

or

```
df.withColumn("new_col",x)
```

or

```
df.withColumn("new_col",sum($"freq"))
```

But none worked.

Comment: Hi @Himanshu, why don't you want to use the groupBy method ?

Comment: it's homework assignment ? Otherwise why would you have such constraints ?

Comment: @baitmbarek not actually but kind of, why use group by when you don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this but be careful, it uses a single partition :

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq(
  (8,1),
  (6,2),
  (2,4)
).toDF("number","freq")


df.withColumn("new_col", sum($"freq").over())
  .show(false)

+------+----+-------+
|number|freq|new_col|
+------+----+-------+
|8     |1   |7      |
|6     |2   |7      |
|2     |4   |7      |
+------+----+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a window over the entire dataframe to do that but I highly recommend not to do it for all the data would need to go to only one partition which would be terrible in terms of performance.

A simple way to do it, very similar to your 1st approach, is:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
val Row(x) = df.select(sum('freq)).head
val new_df = df.withColumn("new_col", lit(x))
```

Comment: I agree with you @Oli, but to get the Row(x) you need to collect your sum (or you'd get a match error).

Comment: You are completely right, I forgot a function. And now it's fixed ;-)